# How to filter a Pandas dataframe to keep entire rows/colums if a criterium is fullfilled?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I am learning Python Pandas and I am having some trouble with data filtering. I have gone through multiple examples and I cannot seem to find an approach that fits my particular need:

In a dataframe with numerical values, I would like to filter rows and columns by the following criterium:

"If ANY value in a row is above a threshold, include the WHOLE row (including values that are below the threshold). Else, discard the row."

This should apply to all rows. Subsequently, I would repeat for columns.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
value = 123
df[df.gt(value).any(axis=1)]
```

For columns, this would be:

```
value = 123
df.loc[:, df.gt(value).any(axis=0)]
```

Comment: Great - thanks! Can't say that I fully get the logic, but it seems to work.

Comment: `gt` creates boolean values (`True` if greater than), `any` aggregates the booleans per row/col (if at least one `True`, then `True`), finally we use this for boolean indexing.

Comment: Thanks. It's the one for columns that I don't understand - and it's actually a great example of why pandas and DataFrame are not that easy to master as soon as one moves beyond typical use cases. If I could have processed colums with df[df.gt(value).any(axis=0)], it would have been logic - although there is probably a perfectly sound explanation as to why you can't. I have many years of experience with Python, but somehow, I just can't grasp Pandas.

Comment: It actually easy once you learn it, you can also use `loc` for the first one: `df.loc[df.gt(value).any(axis=1)]`. `loc` takes `[rows, columns]` as indexers. When you slice rows there is no need to specify columns. For columns you have to specify "all rows" with `:`. Finally, the `df[...]`, where `...` is a boolean Series, can be seen as a shortcut for `df.loc[...]`. Subtleties you need to learn, then it's all straightforward to use.